# Math jargon, interpretation

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

The line says

> A set of positive measure need not contain any nonvoid open interval.

I don't understand quite well what is said. Does this says equivalently that a set of positive measure may or may not contain open intervals?

The example given is for the irrationals in the interval $[0,1]$, which has measure one but it has "holes" due to the rationals in it but these have measure zero. I just want to make sure to have understood correctly the statement.

Comment: your interpretation is correct, "nonvoid" would more usually be known as "nonempty" (as, of course, every set contains the empty open interval)

Comment: @JCAA Standard English, except for the technical terms "set", "measure", "contain", nonvoid", "open", "interval".

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo There are indeed a lot of technical terms here, but the OP's difficulty seems to be with "need not".

Comment: @Andreas This was in response to a somewhat dismissive but now removed comment by someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. Note that the converse is true, i.e. if $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ contains a nonempty open interval, then $m(S)>0$. Another example to help with your understanding is the "fat Cantor set", obtained by starting with $[0,1]$ and successively removing the central open interval of length $a^n$ from every closed interval contained in the $n^\text{th}$ iterate, where $a<1/3$. This will eventually yield a set of positive measure (which is an easy exercise) which contains no open intervals.